# Generic method to return common field from different tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have around 15 tables that I am working with, and I am working on creating audit reports for these tables. All of these tables have a UserId column that gets updated with the last user's Id that made changes. I would like to create a repository method that would allow me to pass in what table entity to use for the method and then just return a list of the UserIds to use on the audit page, instead of allowing the user to type whatever they want in the UserId search field for the audit, I want to supply a dropdown with only the userIds that are in the table that I pass to the method.

I was thinking of something like this:

```
var ids = _repo.GetUserIds(//table entity here, unsure how to declare in signature);
```

Comment: can you not create a stored procedure and then in SQL locate the object name you're looking for as well as a where clause on the object name as well as the Id..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a generic method, with a type parameter that represents your type entity and access the corresponding `DbSet<T>` to get the data from that collection.

```
public int GetUserId<TEntity>()
{
   int userId;
   using (var cts = new MyDbContext())
   {
      userId = ctx.DbSet<TEntity>.FirstOrDefault().Select(e => e.UserId);
   }
   return userId;
}
```

To be able to include the projection lambda `e => e.UserId` you need to make all your classes implement an interface like this:

```
public interface IUserId
{
  public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

And your generic class must have the corresponding type constraint:

```
public RepoClass<T>
   where T:IUserId
{
    // Define the generic method here
}
```