# Entity Framework, Query generic<T> repository with uncertain column name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

Here is what I have:

- Entity framework 5.x, Model first
- Some tables in my database have a UId Column, but not all
- I'm implementing Entity with a generic repository pattern.

What I want:

- When adding a resource, determine if the resource has a UId field, and if so, ensure that it is not already in use.

Here is how I have unsuccessfully tried implementing it;

1. Created a DomainLayer IUniquelyIdentifiable interface that requires the UId field.
2. Created partial classes in the entity project for those entities with UId, and have them implement the interface from step #1.
3. Placed the following code in the generic entity repository

   ```
   if (typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IUniquelyIdentifiable)))
       return DbSet.Any(e => ((IUniquelyIdentifiable)e).UId == UId);

   throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't check if Uid is taken, the resource is not uniquely identifiable");
   ```

However, when I run this code;

- first, my if statement doesn't work. I verified that my partial class(es) indeed implements IUniquelyIdentifiable
- If I comment the 'If' statement to force the query, I get an exception:

> "Schema specified is not valid. Errors: \r\nThe mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type 'ApprovedApplication'. Previously found CLR type 'ToroMessagingService.Entity.ApprovedApplication', newly found CLR type 'ToroMessagingService.Common.DTOModels.ApprovedApplication'."

**Update:**
I found that I could fix this error by renaming my BLL classes. However, now I get the exception that LINQ can only do primitive casts - thus it can't cast to the interface. Now I'm at a loss for how to implement other than brute force.

I'm pretty new at EF (as in first project), so I am greatful for any help.

Below is what I am trying to avoid:

```
if (typeof (T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof (Entity.Account)))
    return Context.Set<Entity.Account>().Any(e => e.UId == UId);

if (typeof (T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof (Entity.User)))
    return Context.Set<Entity.User>().Any(e => e.UId == UId);
```

Comment: EF doesn't distinguish namespaces when mapping CLR types, so you must rename your DTO classes.

Comment: is the second model in that exception message supposed to be the partial/buddy class where you added *IUniquelyIdentifiable* ?

Comment: Thank you, both, it turns out that I did indeed have to rename my BLL classes to different names -- and that fixed my CLR error. However, now I get the error that LINQ can't do the cast to IUniquelyIdentifiable. So maybe I need to step back and ask what the right approach to this problem is.

Comment: I saw a question earlier this week, that was similar, let me see if i can find it, it might be helpful

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022043/generic-method-to-return-common-field-from-different-tables/24027054#24027054 this might be helpful for your most recent comment.

Comment: Thanks, I'll likely try it first thing in the morning.